# How to perform an operational test on the attitude and heading indicators?

Tags: aircraft-maintenance

I just need to know how to perfom it. The only thing I know is that you have to remove them and take them to a "lab".

Comment: With a smartphone and a suitable app, if that's legal and all you need? I just don' know how accurate and precise those things are

Comment: Compass: There will be a compass painted on the ground somewhere at your airfield. Put the aircraft on it and have it point in several directions (every 30° usually). Then make a deviation table. Gyro: take it to the lab and  move it around on some jig that allows to set it at precise angles. See if the indication is correct.